# SASS (gulp) failing

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

My `gulp` is failing. It's a clean install. Installed as non-superuser and using as non-superuser.
I am in `/X/` when running `gulp`.
It works straight from install on other machines.
I have done a `ls -l $(du|grep 'node')|grep 'root'` to try  find any incorrect permissions, but I've found none.

```
╰─ gulp
[00:20:14] Using gulpfile /X/gulpfile.js
[00:20:14] Starting 'cleanJs'...
[00:20:14] Starting 'cleanCss'...
[00:20:14] Starting 'cleanImg'...
[00:20:14] Finished 'cleanJs' after 31 ms
[00:20:14] Finished 'cleanCss' after 21 ms
[00:20:14] Finished 'cleanImg' after 19 ms
[00:20:14] Starting 'cleanAll'...
[00:20:14] Finished 'cleanAll' after 104 μs
[00:20:14] Starting 'buildFromScratch'...
[00:20:14] Starting 'styles'...
[00:20:15] 'styles' errored after 145 ms
[00:20:15] Error: /X/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-47/binding.node: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:423:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/X/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:16:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
[00:20:15] Finished 'buildFromScratch' after 156 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by change in configuration of /etc/fstab. I have a few mounted partitions on the server. One was for /usr, other is for /var/www, where I have my web projects. I had to give flash data=exec, and then reboot system, reinstall node_modules in project directory.

```
UUID="b0d7a164-2536-4c2a-98f7-cdc6c3107c45" /var/www ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered,exec 0 2
```